# What are the specific characteristics of the theories about physics during ancient Greece that distinguish them from contemporary physics?

Tags: physics

What are the specific characteristics of the theories about physics during ancient Greece that distinguish them from contemporary physics? By that, I mean what are the theories during that time characterized as by philosophers? One depends on the modern scientific method and is based on factual observation, the other is more or less purely speculative. This one is easy to observe or note, but are there other characteristics less obvious that differentiated them?

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy! Thanks for your contribution. Please take a quick moment to take the [tour](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour) or find [help](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help). You can perform [searches here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/search) or seek additional clarification at the [meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/). Don't forget, when someone has answered your question, you can click on the checkmark to reward the contributor.

Comment: They are not mathematical in nature in the same way they are after Galileo Galilei, the Greeks did not have the same philosophy of science we have, and they lacked our technology. Analytic geometry (mapping algebra to geometry) didn't even occur until Descartes. If you want to understand better, see [Lloyd's Early Greek Science: Thales to Aristotle](https://books.google.com/books?id=Mym7xTLfNfIC&printsec=frontcover&dq=early+greek+science&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiX9PuUlp3oAhWEGs0KHbSLCKkQ6AEwAHoECAUQAg#v=onepage&q=early%20greek%20science&f=false).

Comment: G.E.R. Lloyd also wrote a follow up volume: [Early Greek Science: After Aristotle](https://books.google.com/books?id=IyQVelEF7C4C&printsec=frontcover&dq=early+greek+science&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiX9PuUlp3oAhWEGs0KHbSLCKkQ6AEwAnoECAMQAg#v=onepage&q=early%20greek%20science&f=false).

Comment: There are laws of motion expresssed mathematically in Aristotle's physics.